# how do I equally divide entries in a database into 5?

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table called Shops and I want to divide this Shop entry into 5. I have 80k entries in my table and I wanted such that user A has access to 16k first shops, user B to the next 16k shops, etc, etc. I know I can use limit, however the primary key/id of Shop is not sequential.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
if (in_array("ADMIN1", $userRoles)) {
            $lowerLimit = 0;
            $upperLimit = $numberOfProspectiveShops/5;
        } else if (in_array("ADMIN2", $userRoles)) {
            $lowerLimit = $numberOfProspectiveShops/5;
            $upperLimit = ($numberOfProspectiveShops/5) * 2;
        } else if (in_array("ADMIN3", $userRoles)) {
            $lowerLimit = ($numberOfProspectiveShops/5) * 2;
            $upperLimit = ($numberOfProspectiveShops/5) * 3;
        } else if (in_array("ADMIN4", $userRoles)) {
            $lowerLimit = ($numberOfProspectiveShops/5) * 3;
            $upperLimit = ($numberOfProspectiveShops/5) * 4;
        } else if (in_array("ADMIN5", $userRoles)) {
            $lowerLimit = ($numberOfProspectiveShops/5) * 4;
            $upperLimit = $numberOfProspectiveShops;
        }


        $prospectiveShopsQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('s')
                ->from("AppMainBundle:ProspectiveShop", 's')
                ->andWhere('s.id <= :upperLimit')  
                ->setParameter('upperLimit', $upperLimit)
                ->andWhere('s.id > :lowerLimit')  
                ->setParameter('lowerLimit', $lowerLimit)
                ->andWhere('s.status IS NULL')  
            ;
```

Comment: If you want to divide them randomly, then I suggest you use the modulus operator on the id (id % 5). The id may not be sequential, but if it has a good distribution, this should give you 5 almost equivalent sets of rows.

Comment: the limit dose not care about the primary key being sequential or not. it will return a fix number of rows. Probably your are confusing this with a where clause on primary key.

Comment: @alinoz yes I do understand the limit doesn't care about primary key, however how do I then get the next 5000 for the 2nd admin?

Comment: you should not use the andWhere on s.id but you should use the limit feature of the mysql. I think you should use the setFirstResult( $offset ) and setMaxResults( $limit ). For the first 5000 the offset  should be equal with 0 and limit with 5000, for then next 5000 the offset=5000 and the limit 5000

Comment: @alinoz sounds good, write that as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @adit please try first because i am not so familiar with symfony and i don't know for sure if it will work.

Comment: @alinoz i tried it and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You should use  the "limit" feature of the mySQL and not a where clause based on id.

This can be achieved by using the setFirstResult($offset) and setMaxResults($limit).
For the first 5000 the offset should be equal with 0 and limit with 5000, for then next 5000 the offset=5000 and the limit 5000

your query builder should looks something like this:

```
$prospectiveShopsQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('s')
            ->from("AppMainBundle:ProspectiveShop", 's')
            ->andWhere('s.status IS NULL')  
            ->setFirstResult($offset)  
            ->setMaxResults($limit)  
        ;
```